# Eclipse & Pydev: How to break on exceptions in my code only

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, breakpoints

Pydev 2.2 added a great functionality allowing us to break on exceptions.

My problem is that I'm getting tons of exceptions from the python libs before I even get to my code.

Is there a way to configure PyDev to only break on exceptions raised in my code?

To be specific: I want to break when the exception occurs - not when it's caught

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Edit]

Note that on newer PyDev versions, PyDev now supports this in the UI: enable the debug perspective and select PyDev > Manage Exception Breakpoints.

[End Edit]

There's nothing in the UI for that, but you can do the following:

In eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug/pysrc/pydevd_frame.py, edit the method **handle_exception**, and make its first lines something as:

```
def handle_exception(self, frame, event, arg):
    if 'my_module' not in self._args[1]:
        return
    ...
    ...
```

(the self._args[1] is the filename where the caught exception was found, so, you can use any heuristic there based on where the code you want to catch exceptions in is located).

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks. I think it would make a useful addition to PyDev's UI